# im working with react admin . Reference fields fetched data would display for a few moments and then disappeared

Tags: reactjs, reference, field, admin, react-admin

```
  <ReferenceField
label='par'
source='parent'
reference='productCategory' \>
<TextField source='name'>
</ReferenceField>
```

my network tab shows ,  first there is a request for all data(till this moment , the fetched data are displaying in reference field ) and then there are requests for all item (from this moment , the reference field dos not show any data).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you change dataProvider? did you create any new file for that and changed functions like "getMany"? please create logs from response of this function to see if there is any issues over there.

Comment: working around getMany  solved the problem . thanku